# What is it called when comparing two opposite people or things

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms, comparisons, literary-techniques

Can someone please let me know what is the technique called when I compare two people who are very different? In my case, it is Donald Woods when he first meets Steve Biko in the film Cry Freedom. I have something along the lines of

> face to face, the privileged and the disadvantaged _____

Comment: i'm thinking it may be juxtaposition? looks like i have answered my own post but this might help someone else!

Comment: This site welcomes people to post answers to their own questions - go ahead!

Comment: "Contrast", perhaps?

Comment: After we stick in a word for the blank, what do you want the phrase to mean?

Answer (score 2):

I would say that the word you are looking for is ***["oppose"](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/oppose)*** or perhaps, as Hot Licks suggest ***["contrast"](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/contrast)***

Answer (score 2):

**[juxtapose](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/juxtapose)**

*Juxtapose* means to discuss or frame together for contrasting effect.

> - 'black-and-white photos of slums were starkly juxtaposed with color images'
>     *[Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/juxtapose)*

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

**Antithesis**: *(literal meaning opposite) is a rhetorical device in which two opposite ideas are put together in a sentence to achieve a contrasting effect.*  (http://literarydevices.net/antithesis/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a name of a literary technique, I would suggest ***foil***:

> In fiction, a **foil** is a character who contrasts with another character (usually the protagonist) in order to highlight particular qualities of the other character.
>   <sub>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foil_(literature))</sub>

But, for your sample sentence, I am not sure what it is you want there, but *clash* would sound about right.