# What device is "lullabies and battle cries", phrases that show two opposite ends of a scale?

Tags: terminology, oxymoron

In lyrics to a poem, the author is commenting on a group of people and mentions their "lullabies and battle cries".

My other half belives this is an oxymoron, however I don't think this is right as it isn't describing something. It isn't saying "their lullaby is a battle cry" it is more an example of opposite ends of a scale.

I suppose another example would be "I witnessed their highs and their lows".

I might be way off here but I don't feel like this is oxymoronic. More examples of extremes of a situation or character.

Comment: Yep, highs and lows are comparable and do not contradict.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is it called when comparing two opposite people or things](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/269524/what-is-it-called-when-comparing-two-opposite-people-or-things) Or [term for coordinate noun phrase containing contrasting things](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/435271/term-for-noun-phrase-containing-contrasting-things/435281#435281)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of contrasting ideas is called

***[antithesis](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/antithesis)***:

> the rhetorical contrast of ideas by means of parallel arrangements of words, clauses, or sentences (as in "action, not words" or "they promised freedom and provided slavery")

(MW)

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: Be sure to pronounce it with stress on the second syllable.